# OpenOffice ScaleToPagesX

Tags: delphi

I try to set up option `ScaleToPagesX = 1` to my OpenOffice document (Calc)

If I haven't specified the name of a file, then option `ScaleToPagesX` is setup normally!

```
FServiceManager := CreateOleObject('com.sun.star.ServiceManager'); 
Desktop := FServiceManager.createInstance('com.sun.star.frame.Desktop');

Document := Desktop.LoadComponentFromURL(private:factory/scalc, '_blank', 0, vArr);

cell := Document.StyleFamilies.getByName('PageStyles').getByName('Default');
cell.ScaleToPagesX := 1;
cell.ScaleToPagesY := 1;
```

But, when I open a document with my name of file, it does not work!
like this:

```
Document := Desktop.LoadComponentFromURL('file:///'+GetCurrentDir()+'/1.xls', '_blank', 0, vArr);

cell:=Document.StyleFamilies.getByName('PageStyles').getByName('Default');
cell.ScaleToPagesX := 1;
cell.ScaleToPagesY := 1;
```

Comment: It is very well possible that `GetCurrentDir()` does not return what you think it should. You should check that, and perhaps use a better way to find the directory. OTOH, you could first hardcode the filename to see if that was the problem. If not, you can always go back to `GetCurrentDir()`.

Comment: file is opened normally by this way. i can set up option LandScape, can write to the cell's.   but i can't  set up option  ScaleToPages  by this way.

Comment: I try to write

Document := Desktop.LoadComponentFromURL('file:///c:/users/Public/Documents/1.xls', '_blank', 0, vArr);

as I expected, it did not help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's works, but not for all document - you need do this for every sheet separately:

```
Document := Desktop.LoadComponentFromURL('file:///'+GetCurrentDir()+'/1.xls', '_blank', 0, vArr);
Sheet := Document.Sheets.getByName('Default'); // if 'Default' is the name of your sheet
cell := Document.StyleFamilies.getByName('PageStyles').getByName(Sheet.PageStyle);
cell.ScaleToPagesX := 1;
cell.ScaleToPagesY := 1;
```